# Nested formulas with error handling

Tags: string, excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have data and would like to use formulas to determine if the installed version is x86 or x64:

```
OSTYPE                                          SHORTPATH                                       VERSION     VERSIOND
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 64-bit  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\JAVA\JRE1.8.0_45\BIN\    8.0.45.14   8.0.45.14 x86
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 64-bit  C:\PROGRAM FILES\JAVA\JRE1.8.0_66\BIN\          8.0.660.18  8.0.660.18 x64
Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 32-bit  C:\PROGRAM FILES\JAVA\JRE6\BIN\                 6.0.510.9   6.0.510.9 x86
```

The intent is that `VERSIOND` will contain the VERSION value and then append either `x86` for a 32bit install or `x64` for 64bit install.

```
If SHORTPATH contains "(x86)" then it's a 32bit install
If SHORTPATH doesn't contain "(x86)" and OSTYPE contains "64-bit" then it's a 64bit install
If SHORTPATH doesn't contain "(x86)" and OSTYPE contains "32-bit" then it's a 32bit install
```

I've almost got it working via:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("(x86)";D2));IF(SEARCH("64-bit";C2)>0;CONCATENATE(E2;" x64");CONCATENATE(E2;" x86"));CONCATENATE(E2;" x86"))
```

Column C is `OSTYPE`, column D is `SHORTPATH` and column E is `VERSION`.

It works except when `OSTYPE` is 32-bit, and it's because of `SEARCH("64-bit";C2)>0` returning `#VALUE!`'

How to add the second ISERROR for handling that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shorter version:

```
=E2&" "&IF(AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("x86";D2));NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("64-bit";C2))));"x64";"x86")
```

Comment: Thanks, works great and is more simple than why I had attempted

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the result in column E to be concatenated with " x86" if either SHORTPATH contains "(x86)" or OSTYPE contains 32-bit, otherwise you want it concatenated with " x64" you could use `OR` to describe when you want to use " x86" and not even explicitly search for "64-bit":

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("(x86)",D2))),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("32-bit",C2)))),CONCATENATE(E2," x86"),CONCATENATE(E2," x64"))
```

The above was tested, but you seem to be using a regional setting which uses `;` in place of `,`, so I guess that would be:

```
=IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("(x86)";D2)));NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("32-bit";C2))));CONCATENATE(E2;" x86");CONCATENATE(E2;" x64"))
```